# SQL Many-To-Many multiple items per column

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

Sorry about the title, as I'm new to SQL and I don't know how to explain the problem appropriately...

I have 5 tables.

Delivery

```
ID | Time      |
---------------|
1  | 1999-01-01|
2  | 1999-01-01|
3  | 1999-01-01|
```

Delivery_Items

```
Delivery_ID | Order_ID|
----------------------|
1           | 1       |
2           | 2       |
3           | 3       |
```

Food

```
ID | Name | Price  |
-------------------|
1  |Eggs  | 3.00   |
2  |Bacon | 1.50   |
3  |Ham   | 4.00   |
```

Ordered_Items

```
Order_ID | Item_ID  |
--------------------|
1        |  1       |
1        |  1       |
1        |  2       |
1        |  3       |
2        |  2       |
2        |  1       |
3        |  3       |
```

Orders

```
ID | Total_Price  |
------------------|
1  | 11.50        |
```

I would like to Join them together for an expected result of something like this

```
Delivery_ID    | Food.Name            | Total Price |
----------------------------------------------------|
1              |Eggs, Eggs, Bacon, Ham| 11.50       |
2              |Bacon, Eggs           | 4.50        |
3              |Ham                   | 4.00        |
```

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT
    O.Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(F.Name
        SEPARATOR ','),
    O.Total
FROM
    Food F
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Ordered_Items OI ON OI.Item_ID = F.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Orders O ON O.Id = OI.order_Id
GROUP BY O.Id;
```

Which results in

```
Delivery_ID    | Food.Name                     | Total Price |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
NULL           |Eggs, Bacon, Ham(trash values) | NULL        |
1              |Eggs, Eggs, Bacon, Ham         | 11.50       |
2              |Bacon, Eggs                    | 4.50        |
3              |Ham                            | 4.00        |
```

How do I get rid of that first NULL line?
And by trash values I mean their IDs don't appear in any Ordered_Items row.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Is "Item_ID" in your Ordered Items the id of the Food?

Comment: Yes, the Item_ID in ordered items is the id of the Food

Comment: Join them together for an expectd result? This is no explanation of what you want to do. You want to select a list of *what*? Of all delivery dates for a certain order? The maximum delivery date for a certain order? A row per delivery containing all its orders? Please explain. And please extend your sample data, so we see at least two different orders and at least one order with multiple delivery dates.

Comment: A row per delivery containing all its orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join two or more tables you need to use Join and the query for this will look like-

'`SELECT Delivery_Items.Delivery_ID,Food.Name,Orders.Total_Price FROM 
Delivery_Items  JOIN Ordered_items ON Delivery_Items.Delivery_ID=Ordered_Items.Order_ID
JOIN Food ON ordered_items.Order_ID=Food.ID
JOIN Orders ON Delivery_Items.Delivery_ID=Orders.ID`

So, As we need to look the tables we start joining tables.Thus , first we join Delivery_Items and Ordered_Items which created a temporary result making another table and then this is joined by another table and the process goes on.

1.First choose which columns you want to show in the end result

2.Select all those columns

3.Look up the tables that you need to join to get the result

4.Then in the sql query  join those according to table1.primarykeytable2.foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you need to know the total price per order.
You can try this:

```
SELECT o.Order_ID, SUM(f.Price)
  FROM Ordered_Items oi INNER JOIN Food f
  ON oi.Item_ID = f.ID
  GROUP BY o.Order_ID;
```

As for the items, I think you cannot do it, since you cannot aggregate a field of type VARCHAR.
You can try the below:

```
SELECT o.Order_ID, f. Name
  FROM Ordered_Items oi INNER JOIN Food f
  ON oi.Item_ID = f.ID
  ORDER BY o.Order_ID;
```

The result will be somthing like the below:

```
Order_ID | Name  
--------------------
1        |  Eggs       
1        |  Eggs       
1        |  Bacon      
1        |  Ham       
2        |  Bacon      
2        |  Eggs       
3        |  Ham
```

Hope this helps!